# Recommended cooking uses for applejack?

Tags: substitutions

I recently had a recipe that called for applejack (apple brandy) in the glaze. Now I've got a bunch of this stuff lying around, and I'm looking for cooking applications for it.

Can it be substituted for regular brandy in recipes? Are there any particular situations where you would recommend its use?

Comment: Just do shots :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple brandy goes particularly well with pork chops or pork tenderloin. It would also be a  good substitute when a dessert calls for brandy, such as Baked Fruit (maybe Pears?), or an apple cake.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Mike Sherov's suggestions.

Additionally, I like sweet brandy-based glazes on chicken. For example, here's a recipe from a Rachael Ray book: [Brandy and Orange Chicken](http://www.justrightmenus.com/recipe.php?id=112) (from: [Rachael Ray 30-Minute Meals 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1891105108))

Regarding substitution. Unless the recipe asks for a specific kind of non-apple Brandy, you should be fine substituting. Just realize that your food won't taste exactly like someone else's and may not taste as the recipe author originally intended. This isn't necessarily a bad thing; just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Applejack can be used to add apple flavor in pie crust (particularly apple) in place of some of the water.  http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/good-eats/super-apple-pie-recipe/index.html